# What should I change or add for this posNeg code to work out?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class posyNegy
{
    
//Given 2 int values, return true if one is negative and one is positive. Except if the parameter "negative" is true, then return true only if both are negative.

//posyNegy(1, -2, false) → true
//posyNegy(-3, 1, false) → true
//posyNegy(-6, -2, true) → true
   

 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
     public boolean posyNegy(int a, int b, boolean negative)
     {
      if (a<0 && b>0 && negative==false)
        {
        return true;
        }
  
    else if(a>0 && b<0 && negative==false)
    {
    return true;
    }
     else if(a<0 && b<0 && negative==true)
    {
    return true;
    }
    else 
    {
    return false;
    }
        }
    }
}
```

Can't find out where is the error. Probably need to add more.
Task:
Write the code that will take the 2 int values and return true if one is negative and one is positive.

Except if the parameter "negative" is true, then return true only if both are negative.

MAKE SURE TO IT works on the three examples

EXAMPLE RETURNS
posyNeg(1, -2, false) → true
posyNegy(-3, 1, false) → true
posyNegy(-6, -2, true) → true

Comment: What is your output vs expected output? I know you specified one in the question, but it is unclear.

Comment: You can't declare one method inside of another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify as well as keep it clean this way:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(posyNegy(1, 2, true));
        System.out.println(posyNegy(1, 2, false));
        System.out.println(posyNegy(-1, 2, true));
        System.out.println(posyNegy(-1, 2, false));
        System.out.println(posyNegy(1, -2, true));
        System.out.println(posyNegy(1, -2, false));
        System.out.println(posyNegy(-1, -2, true));
        System.out.println(posyNegy(-1, -2, false));
    }

    public static boolean posyNegy(int a, int b, boolean negative) {
        if (negative) {
            if (a < 0 && b < 0) {
                return true;
            }
        } else if (a < 0 && b > 0 || a > 0 && b < 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
false
false
false
true
false
true
true
false
```

Comment: I think your third and fifth test should output false. The second if condition does not test if the parameter is not negative.

Comment: @MichaelChatiskatzi - You are right. Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Negative: x < 0, not-negative; x >= 0.

To combine requirements, you can do the following:

1. Write the code that will take the 2 int values and return true if one is negative and one is positive.

   ```
    return (a < 0) != (b < 0);
   ```
2. Except if the parameter "negative" is true, then return true only if both are negative.

   ```
    if (negative) {
        return (a < 0) && (b < 0);
    }
    return (a < 0) != (b < 0);
   ```
3. Simplify

   ```
    boolean an = a < 0;
    boolean bn = b < 0;
    return (negative && an && bn) 
        || an != bn;
   ```

The "except ..." throws the condition in front of the already construed definition. "one of" / "both" can be done with "`!=`" and "`==`".

Do not use "P == false" or "P == true" but "`!P`" resp. "`P`".

Comment: Excellent explanation and great step by step instructions!